# How can I get the average number of blank cells between cells with numbers/letters?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a column, let's say column A, which looks something like this:

```
1234
BLANK
BLANK
BLANK
1234
BLANK
BLANK
1234
BLANK
BLANK
BLANK
BLANK
BLANK
1234
BLANK
BLANK
BLANK
BLANK
BLANK
1234
BLANK
BLANK
1234
BLANK
1234
BLANK
BLANK
BLANK
BLANK
1234
```

Basically I'm trying to display the average number of blank cells there are down the column until a cell with a "1234" comes up. I've never done this before and I can't find any information out there on how to do it.

Comment: are you looking for 3.142857143
?

Comment: I'm not sure. What do you use to get that result?

Comment: Maybe you should figure out what you actually are looking for before posting random vague thoughts masquerading as a question.

Comment: Maybe you should try actually reading my question thoroughly. This IS what I am looking for.

Comment: ...and what, pray tell, is your expected result? Please, please, inquiring minds want to know! Count it on your fingers and toes if you have to.

Comment: Seems the others get what I'm saying. Why can't you?

Comment: Yeah, you're a genius. I'm sure I didn't have a clue as to what you were guessing at.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you BLANKS are not Text (but empty cells) and your data is columnar starting in A1 then I think you need:

The total of all cells in the range: `=MATCH(1E+100,A:A)`  or `30`
The total of non-blank cells in the range: `=COUNTA(A:A)`  or `8`

From which:

```
=(MATCH(1E+100,A:A)-COUNTA(A:A))/(COUNTA(A:A)-1)
```

or `3.14`.

Comment: I tried that and the result I get is -0.016 which is definitely not right considering there's usually a few blank cells in between from what I can see.

Comment: You might want to check for non-blank cells. I used your formula on my sample data and came up with the same result my own effort returned. e.g. 3.142857143

Comment: Just tested it again. It seems to work fine now. The A:A wasn't working, but when I changed it to A18:A37 that made all the difference because when I was using A:A, it was including all the blank cells way down the column.

Comment: Yeah, mistakes in reformatting sample data will happen occasionally when the op can't put in the effort to figure out a code block.

Comment: Oh god no! Don't remove your post. I've given up on this genius who apparently doesn't understand how an average works long ago.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your data is at A1:A30 , put these at B2:E2, then drag it downwards..

```
B2  --->   =IF(A2="",B1+1,0)
C2  --->   =IF(B2=0,B1,"")
D2  --->   =IF(C2="",D1,D1+1)
E2  --->   =IF(C2="","",SUM($C$2:C2)/D2)
```

last value @ Column E should be your desired values..

Hope it helps.. (:

Comment: Thanks, but I'm trying to display a number in a single cell which tells me the average amount of blanks between cells with a letter or number in them. I mean, I don't want a whole lot of other stuff showing up in an entire column.

Comment: sorry, I don't know how to do it.. btw I've edited my ans to get 3.142857143 .